# Alternating Fold[] of two functions, each having 3 arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I have a function s, which has a list and two numbers as arguments and creates a list:

```
s[list,n1,n2],
```

and a function t, which also has a list and two numbers as arguments and creates a list:

```
t[list,n3,time]
```

I want to create the following nested structure:

```
t[s[t[s[t[s[list,n1,n2],n2,time3],n2,n1],n1,time2],n1,n2],n2,time1]
```

But I want to call t and s not only 3 times, but k-times.
Extra bonus would be a list which contains these nested structures for different values of k with $1\leq k \leq K$.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
desired = t[s[t[s[t[s[list, n1, n2], n2, time3], n2 ,n1], n1, time2], n1, n2], n2, time1]

k = 3;
n1n2 = {n2, n1};
times = Symbol["time" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Reverse[Range[k]];

Fold[t[s[#, ## & @@ (n1n2 = RotateRight[n1n2])], n1n2[[-1]], #2] &, list, times]
```

> t[s[t[s[t[s[list, n1, n2], n2, time3], n2, n1], n1, time2], n1, n2], n2, time1]

```
% == desired
```

> True